# How to clear "run a comand" history?

Tags: 20.04, bash, bash-history

I have been trying to clear ubuntu's 'run my command' history but cannot find any way. if any one have the solution please tell

[image]

Comment: bash history? See: https://superuser.com/questions/384366/remove-a-certain-line-from-bash-history-file/384378#384378

Comment: Related:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241049/how-to-clear-history-from-run-command-alt-f2-on-gnome

Answer (score 2):

There is no user exposed way to clear the command history of the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> "Run a Command" dialog, but you can use the following command:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell command-history
```

Comment: Thank you So much for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. Please "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark if this helped you to show others that your question has been addressed.